# Purpose of XOR-ing with 0?

Tags: ffmpeg, xor, lzw

So i have a static hash table and before adding a code in the table, index is being XOR-ed with 0. Why is that the case if index of the table is already declared as integer?

```
h = 0;
h ^= (i << LZW_HASH_SHIFT);
if (h >= LZW_HASH_SIZE)
{
    h -= LZW_HASH_SIZE;
}
s->tab[h].code = i;
s->tab[h].suffix = i;
s->tab[h].hash_prefix = LZW_PREFIX_EMPTY;
```

This source code is part of FFmpeg LZW encoder lib.

Comment: I cannot find this code, and I'd want to see the context around it. The closest I can see is [here](https://github.com/uwehermann/easybox-904-lte-firmware/blob/master/package/ffmpeg/src/libavcodec/lzwenc.c#L173), but it doesn't match your code.

Comment: Yep that's it. I just copied source code from `hash` function to `clearTable()`, because compiler wasn't inlining properly.

Comment: Basicly `hash` function does XOR operation, but when you're clearing the table and filling it up with default values, zeros are being passed to `hash` function as `head` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

In the original code, the `hash` function is called from other places in code, and it makes no sense to duplicate a function just to avoid one line in a special case when that line does nothing. Thus, it does nothing when called from `clearTable` (wasting a negligible amount of time), but does something sensible when called with a parameter that is not zero.

In your case, the sole purpose is to showcase how blind copy-pasting is bad, I suppose :)

Comment: Yeah, I just realised that, my bad. Only reason why i copy-pasted `hash` code into `clearTable` is because `inline` was not working properly since the amount of time needed using `inline` was incredibly larger than with copy-pasting the code which is basicly inlining.

Comment: Also, if you're familiar with FFmpeg could you explain to me what is sole purpose of `put_bits` lib?

Comment: In general, if you have an unrelated inquiry, you should ask a new StackOverflow question. Anyway, `put_bits` allows you to pack bits into an array of integers. Imagine you are packing sardines into cans fitting 8 sardines. If you are given 13 sardines, you will fill one whole can and put some in the second, leaving space for 3 more sardines in the second box. If given one more sardine, you lay it in the second can next to the existing ones. Get 6 more, and you will be left with two full cans and half-full third. `put_bits` does the same, but each can is a 32-bit integer, and each fish 0 or 1.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i finally understand what's going on.